# Count $n \times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let’s count all the $n \times n$ matrices whose entries are $0, 1,$ or $2$ such that each row and each column have exactly one $1$ and one $2$, while the other entries are $0$.

Would this be a $3 \times 3$ matrix? I'm not sure how to start this problem. Would this be an example? 
 $$\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Comment: It would be a $3 \times 3$ *or larger* matrix.  And yes, what you've proposed fits the conditions.

Comment: How about $$\pmatrix{1&2&0&0\\0&1&2&0\\0&0&1&2\\2&0&0&1}?$$

Comment: Hint: Start with the case when all 1's are placed on the main diagonal and count how many ways are there to place the 2. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an example.  A good start is to find how many ways there are to place the $1$s.  Given a way you place the $1$s, how many ways are there to place $2$s?  You should be able to convince yourself that it is the same for all the ways of placing $1$s.

For general $n$ we can place the $1$s in $n!$ ways.  The problem of placing the $2$s is equivalent for all of these with the problem of placing them in the case where the $1$s are along the main diagonal.  If we list the column numbers of the $2$s in row number order we need a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $n$.  There are $\left[\frac {n!}e\right]$ of these where the square brackets represent rounding to the nearest whole number.  The total number is then 
$$n!\left[\frac {n!}e\right]$$

Comment: I don't think it's quite that simple.  If you're not at least a little bit careful of your placement of $2$s, you may find that there's no legal position for the last $2$.  For example, place $1$s along the main diagonal of a $3 \times 3$ matrix and then places $2$s in the other two corners.  There's no legal place for a $2$ in the second row.

Comment: @RobertShore:  You are correct, so that is not a legal way to place the $2$s given the placing of the $1$s.  I believe that given a placing of the $1$s there are two ways to place the $2$s

Comment: For a $3 \times 3$ matrix that's correct, but the problem wants a solution for general $n \times n$ matrices.  The issue is determining how many "legal" placements of $2$s exist given a specific legal placement of $1$s.  That answer isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: @RobertShore: See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Firstly choose the position of the $1$'s which are $(k,\sigma(k))$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation. There are $n!$ ways to do so.

Then choose the position of the $2$'s which are $(k,\tau(k))$ where $\tau$ is a permutation such that $\tau(k) \neq \sigma(k)$.

For $n = 2,3,4$ there are $1,2,9$ such $\tau$'s.

The problem remains to find the number of $\tau$'s

Edit : The number of $\tau$'s is the number of deragements  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement  which, as said in the wikipedia article is $\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor$  aka the nearest integer to $\frac{n!}{e}$

So the answer to your question is : $$\lfloor \frac{n!}{e} + \frac{1}{2} \rfloor  n!$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's build a general $n\times n$ matrix $M$ satisfying the conditions and count the number $f(n)$ of distinct choices that could be made.

1. The first decision is the locations of the 1's for each column; this can be done in $n!$ ways.
2. Let $a_1...a_n$ be the sequence from the previous step, i.e. $a_i=j$ means $M_{ji}=1$, and let $b_1...b_n$ be any other permutation such that $b_i\neq a_i$. This $b$ is our second choice.

How many $b$ are there? For a fixed $a$ this is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $\{1,...,n\}$, therefore the solution is $$f(n)= n!D_n = (n!)^2\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$ or $n!$ times (any of the other formulas in the aforementioned link).